# Unexplained CSS property on sub menu in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've built this relatively ugly thing that I am trying to make less ugly (images are all placeholder atm).

http://samcampsall.co.uk/DA/

Action point one - there is a sub menu for some of the main nav links, which pops up OK. However it is adding height to the nav button underneath and I can't figure out why (please see the bottom two nav links 'Equipment' and 'The Guide').

I've tried changing these links' position in the menu and it always affects the link underneath by increasing the height (and increasing the ugly). Firebug is telling me that the affected links have increased height but I can't figure out why.

After some more playing it appears that the sub-menus add a margin or padding to their bottom pushing the item underneath down. I can reduce this by using a margin-bottom:-##px, but I can't work out why its there in the first place.

This is probably because I am fairly incompetent - any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have the text box for "the guide" very small so its dropping lines to fit.  If you try

```
   text-indent: -105px;
```

on that link you'll see it all moves up.

You would want something like this to only target that box:

```
#menu-item-14 a {text-indent: -105px;}
```

and then something like

```
#menu-item-14 ul {text-indent:0px;}
```

for the submenu.  But this is a hack. you would want to see the rest of your code why that box is coming so small

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'd wondered if this was just an issue of too much text or a line break or something, but I don't think this is the issue. You'll see I've edited the label down ('The') but I've still got the same issue.

Comment: try making your menu-main-nav-menu-container a { block with padding}, and dont apply the css to the li a